# ¿Como puedo mandar ciertos tipos de datos de ciertos tipos de campos en una tabla a ciertos campos de otra bd en SQL?

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo la idea pero me marca errores en los paréntesis y en las comas despues de elegir cuales se van a mandar como se puede hacer o si se debe de hacer un insert into por cada campo de tabla que quiero enviar?

```
CREATE TRIGGER [OtherTH]
   ON ComercialISP.dbo.orgProduct
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Purchasing_be.dbo.[FabComponents t](Component,Dept,Cata) 
     SELECT (dbo.orgProduct.ProducName , dbo.orgProduct.Category1 , dbo.orgProduct.Category2 )
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Category1 <> 'Tela' AND Category2 <> 'Yarns'
    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes varios errores:

```
CREATE TRIGGER OtherTH
   ON dbo.orgProduct
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO Purchasing_be.dbo.[FabComponents t](Component,Dept,Cata) 
     SELECT ProducName , Category1 , Category2 
    FROM inserted
    WHERE Category1 <> 'Tela' AND Category2 <> 'Yarns'

END
GO
```

Los paréntesis sobran. **dbo.orgProduct** no existe, o mejor dicho no está referenciada, ni le hace falta. En su lugar, y como supongo quieres mandar los registros que se están insertando, por tanto utilizas las columnas de la pseudo-tabla `inserted`.

[Trigger After Insert.](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/12/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-insert/)